# Interface knows its implementers

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

Can i specify somehow in the interface that all its implementations would be inherited from certain abstract class?

Comment: Why must they implement *both* your interface and an abstract class?

Comment: Sounds like you should add the interface methods to the abstract class and remove the interface.

Comment: Make the abstract class implement the interface, I fail to see the use of this but I think this is the closest match to your requirement.

Comment: @Vladimir - if you're doing this in order to accomodate future changes without breaking existing clients, just use an abstract base class (*without the interface*)

Comment: I need to pass list of objects that implement that interface and are inherited from certain abstract class in the method. Also I have no permissions to change abstract class.

Comment: @Vladimir - Can you change the method signature to accept a List<SomethingBase> instead of an List<ISomething> ?

Comment: @Gishu No, because not all SomethingBase objects have ISomething implemented.

Comment: @Vladimir - I was assuming that SomethingBase implements ISomething. So it seems that the abstract class and the interface are not related. In which case, I'm afraid you'll have to handle this via code - do a runtime type-check and handle it accordingly. However I would review my design carefully to confirm that there are no alteranatives before I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it known via comment / documentation but you cannot enforce this via compile-time checks/syntax.

If you define a base class for all implementations and it really cuts down the work for implementers, no reason why they wouldn't do it. e.g. ICollection and CollectionBase in the .Net framework

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose the interface, either define the interface methods as abstract methods within you abstract class and do away with the interface, or make the interface internal and don't expose it to your users.

Comment: I can`t change abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Put the interface on the abstract class and derive from this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Directly "NO"
Unless you find some trick/workaround, which I strongly doubt!